# function that fills NaN in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change NaN with some values as it is obvious in the code, i tried so many times and it didn't work 
i tried one single column and It did not work

```py
# replace NaN value! If string column, then using mode otherwise median
for col in train:
    if train[col].dtype == 'object':
        train[col] = train[col].fillna(train[col].mode())
    else:
        train[col] = train[col].fillna(train[col].median())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlcyd.png)

Comment: Did you mean ```for col in train.columns:...```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `train` is your dataframe (and not the columns) you will need to adjust your `for`-statement as per below. Also, `.mode()` return a Series so change as per below.

```
for col in train.columns:
    if train[col].dtype == 'object':
        train[col] = train[col].fillna(train[col].mode()[0])
    else:
        train[col] = train[col].fillna(train[col].median())
```